# Running Azure MVC Web Site With Web Role Side By Side

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles

I am re-learning some forgotten skills and started off by creating a simple MVC 5.0 web application deployed to Azure with a SQL Server backend. I then thought it would be fun to run some reports - this was a challenge as you need to use GDI+ and have extended privelages ([AZURE Hosting & MVC5 Reporting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21669522/azure-hosting-mvc5-reporting)), to get around this I thought I had converted my Web Application into a Web Role, but it would appear all I did was to create a Web Role that "hosts" my web application. I have made this assumption as I have a Startup.cs and no WebRole.cs in the root of the Web Application project.

So the Web Application is running very nicely and I would now like to extend the functionality to email on a schedule. Luckily, there is a tutorial for this (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-dotnet-multi-tier-app-storage-3-web-role/) which I have been following unfortunately due to my actions above I think something has gone wrong in my conversion and I am now stuck! I think this as I included the WebRole.cs in the root folder of my Web Application ([Add WebRole.cs - and have it called - in an existing ASP.NET MVC site converted to web role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719967/add-webrole-cs-and-have-it-called-in-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-site-converted)), however, when I placed a breakpoint in the file it did not break/stop.

One of my problems is I dont know what I have implemented incorrectly as I am using the icons in the solution explorer to understand what is what and they seem to correspond to the sample email solution. As the reports require GDI+ and this is only available when using a web role I have to assume that is working correctly as my reports are generating in Azure. The other behaviour which I noticed is that when running the sample it loads the storage emulator, however, once I have made my changes to my project the storage emulator does not load?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

David

EDIT: Ok I remember what I did now, in the solution explorer I right clicked the project and went convert to Azure this created a role in the .Azure project

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this very embarrassing, when you use the convert option as described above Visual Studio does not make the Azure project the startup project. Once the Azure project was made the startup project everything began working as expected!